# Parent field returning null in second child Activity even though it has been initialized in first Activity

Tags: java, android

Let's say I have:
A parent activity **ParentActivity**  with an uninitialized public String field **name**

```
public class ParentActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    public String name;
}
```

Also, two children activities **ChildOneActivity** and **ChildTwoActivity**, where **ChildOneActivity** initializes the String **name** and launches **ChildTwoActivity**

```
public class ChildOneActivity extends ParentActivity{
    name = "I'm a pizza";
    launchChildTwoAct();
} 

public class ChildTwoActivity extends ParentActivity{
    Log.d(TAG, "the value of name is: " + name);
}
```

**Problem:** The value of name is printing null. I'm confused because both children have the same parent... I'm trying to achieve this without EventBus, Intents, bundles, or interface

**Question:** Does that mean that the **name** field instance in the parent has to be static, otherwise name will always be null?

Comment: It is just inheritance. If You extend a Class you get fields to that class but every instance of that class has its own fields. If You want to have one common field Value should be static. Just imagine what would happen if Your code was working. E.g. You have 2 Buttons. On one, You change tag and the other also changes tag becouse Button extend View and View has a Tag field

Comment: Great example by the way, that really helps. Thanks.